# How to pass % in URL validation in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I have the following route:

```
Route::get('/delete/{var}',
    'MyController@delete')
    ->where("var", "[A-Za-z0-9\-\.\%]+");
```

My problem is that I want to allow `%` to be passed with `var`. Unfortunately the following two options did not work out for me:

```
"[A-Za-z0-9\-\.\%]+"
"[A-Za-z0-9\-\.%]+"
```

I'm trying to pass the folliwng URL:

```
domain.tld/delete/something.com%2Fhtml%2Fsomestring%2Ffolder
```

If I remove the `%` from my URL it's working. So how could I validate the URL in order to use the `%` sign in it?

**Edit**

This is strange: If I remove the `->where()` check in the route completely, it's still not working if there's a `%` in the URL. How could that be?

Comment: Try double-escaping your dot: `[A-Za-z0-9\-\\.\%]+`

Comment: @Phiter: Still not working

Comment: Your original regex looks good. Are you sure it's that at fault?

Comment: Yes, everything works as expected - I could not determine any errors. Also I realized, that if it's just one `%` it works, but if `var` contains multiple `%` it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uses `filter_var() with the`FILTER_VALIADTE_URL` option which doesn't allow umlauts. You can write a custom validator or use the regex validation rule in combination with a regular expression.

```
"url" => "required|regex:".$regex
```

Or better specify the rules as array to avoid problems with special characters:

```
"url" => array("required", "regex:".$regex)
```

For example

```
$input = Input::all();
$validationInput = $input;
$validationInput['url'] = str_replace(['ä','ö','ü'], ['ae','oe','ue'], $validationInput['url']);
$validator = Validator::make(
    $validationInput,
    $rules
);
if($validator->passes()){
    Model::create($input); // don't use the manipulated $validationInput!
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I was not talking about umlauts, instead the `%` is not passed correctly, I have no umlauts in my URL.